# Select Values based on extracting values PHPMyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, subquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkOcw.png)

My table has data as shown in the picture.
I selected the `SiteInstanceID` value based on a selection from another column "`AttributeValue`".

```
SELECT
   `SiteInstanceID` 
FROM
   `sitecomponentattributevalues` 
WHERE
   `AttributeValue` = 00069
```

Now I want to select all data from the same table where the `SiteInstanceID` is `61` (the extracted value from the above code)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QkYb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from sitecomponentattributevalues s
where exists (
    select 1 
    from sitecomponentattributevalues s1 
    where s1.SiteInstanceID = s.SiteInstanceID and s1.AttributeValue = '0069'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join both SELECT statements with WHERE IN like this

```
SELECT * FROM `sitecomponentattributevalues`
WHERE `SiteInstanceID` IN 
(SELECT `SiteInstanceID` FROM `sitecomponentattributevalues`
WHERE `AttributeValue` = 00069)
```